# How can I make my setValue +1 code to go 12345 instead of 11111

Tags: reactjs, counter

I am trying to create a counter (like an upvote system) called the lumen system that when you click a light bulb sprite there is a counter next to the message that goes from being invisble to a 1 magically appearing. Currently (albeit ugly as fuck) I managed to get to the point where when you click the sprite, the 1 appears except when you click it again it adds another 1. For example click it once: 1 (chat message)(sprite), click it twice: 11 (chat message) (sprite), click it three times: 111 (chat message)(sprite).

This is code all located at the bottem of my App.js that I believe to be relevant, please let me know if you need something else.

```
    function ChatMessage(props) {
  const { text, uid, photoURL } = props.message;

  const messageClass = uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received';

  const [lumenValue, setLumenValue] = useState(0);

  return (<>
    <div className={`message ${messageClass}`}>
      <img src={photoURL || 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/23/abott@adorable.png'} />
      <button onClick={() => setLumenValue(lumenValue + 1 )}>  </button>
      <p>{text}</p>
      <p>{lumenValue}</p>
    </div>
  </>)
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Sounds odd, it sounds kind of like as if it starts out as an empty string, not as a number?

Comment: @CertainPerformance You're exactly right, problem solved thank you!